# How is the tokenization done in Stanford POS tagger?

Tags: stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I am going to use Stanford POS tagger to tag the sentences. I want to split the documents into sentences and then sentences to tokens. As I am using java for the first time I just want to run the tagger from the command line.

As I'm running the tagger, it gives the output but it gives a warning "untokenizable".
What does this warning mean? Is the tokenization not implicitly done by the tagger?

I have tried to run the command for splitting the text into sentences that you have specified but it doesn't work. The tagger gives the error that it could not open the path.

I also want to know that how can I input number of text files and get their output in corresponding files so that all of the output is not jumbled.

Comment: Maybe it is better to ask the mailing list: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml#Mail

Comment: Or at least add the stanford-nlp tag :-)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the Stanford POS tagger includes a high-quality, deterministic tokenizer, which is used unless you say the text is already tokenized. For formal English text, it is superior to most other tokenizers out there, though it isn't fully suitable for sms, tweets, etc.

An untokenizable warning means that there are byte/character sequences in the input that it can't process.

Normally what this actually means is this: The default character encoding of the tagger is utf-8 (Unicode), but your document is in some other encoding such as an 8 bit encoding like iso-8859-1 or Windows cp1252.  You can convert the document or specify an input document encoding with the -encoding flag.

But it could also mean that there is a rare character in the input that it doesn't know about. Normally in those cases, if it's just an occasional character, you can just ignore the messages. You can choose whether the characters are deleted or turned into 1 character tokens.

There isn't at present a facility for running it on a bunch of files with one command. You'll either need to run it separately on each file, or to write your own code for that.